# Is there a way of inserting a flow chart into a word document using access vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-access-2016

I am trying to insert a 3D flow chart into a word document using VBA, I have been asked to do this and I have no idea how to do this even after some research.

Sorry I have no code examples because I am at a loss on how to do this, and could probably misleading if I posted any :-)

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use vba across different programs but adds a bit more complexity - added to which vba uses different objects and methods depending which program you're in.

Your best bet is to record as much of the macro as you can inside MS word, then edit the vba and transfer it to MS Access (I assume you'll be working with variables from the MS Access file or VBProject anyway).

[This post](https://exceloffthegrid.com/controlling-word-from-excel-using-vba/) would be an excellent starting point - yes, it's made for use in Excel, but the Word Object Model is used the same way.

Comment: Great thnx, I will look into it